# How to disable p:progressBar transition animation in PF 6

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I would like to **disable animation** of the `p:progressBar` transition in **PF 6**. In PF 7 this is possible via `animationDuration="0"`. Is there any workaround for PF 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your Javascript to override the ProgressBar and remove the animation.

```javascript
PF('progress').setValue = function(value) {
        if(value >= 0 && value<=100) {
            if(value == 0) {
                this.jqValue.hide().css('width', '0%').removeClass('ui-corner-right');

                this.jqLabel.hide();
            }
            else {
                if(this.cfg.labelTemplate) {
                    var formattedLabel = this.cfg.labelTemplate.replace(/{value}/gi, value);
                    this.jqLabel.text(formattedLabel).show();
                }
            }

            this.value = value;
            this.jq.attr('aria-valuenow', value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, my question is ambiguous, your solution disables animation at all (which is still good to know +1), while I was looking for disabling progress transition animation from value a% to value b%, this is done simply by setting `PF('progress').cfg.animationDuration = 0;` (your example led me to examine ProgressBar Client API). If you include also this variant in your solution, I would accept your answer.

Comment: `PF('progress').cfg.animationDuration = 0;` works only in PF 7 (my bad, I tested in wrong environment). `$.fx.off = true;` will disable effects/animations for all elements, I need to figure out how to disable/remove animation of the `PF('progress').jqValue`.

Comment: I updated my answer to turn off the animation just for Widget PF('progress') instead of all ProgressBars.